# How to automatically restart node server

Tags: node.js, server, debian, restart, forever

how can I automatically restart my node js server every hour **automatically**. There is a bug that only shows up after 1 hours and I want to be able to run it through the night. I'm already using forever.

Comment: Would this be better posted on Server Fault? Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I like [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) for running my node apps but when it comes to keeping things alive then I rely on [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/). But If it really crashes every hour then you are better off trying to fix that bug.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever). I've not used it myself, but seems to do what you want.